# wpf, I create dynamically many window form at runtime, but how can I grab these window form's identity?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to send different messages to specified window, but I do not konw how to identify a given window from all. Is the way to use the window's property of "Name"?

Comment: You want to get the title at the top of the window?

Comment: Yes, you can use Name or Title properties.

Comment: no. I want to send a message to a window, but I don't konw how to identify that window because there are many windows created dynamically.

Comment: So you're trying to get the window's handle (HWND)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own Window class

```
public class MyCoolWindow : Window
{
   public string WindowKey {get;set;}
}
```

and on every window create add a new window to a glbal collection, for exmaple:

```
var windows = new List<MyCoolWindow>(); 

public void AddAndShowWindow(MyCoolWindow wnd)
{        
    windows.Add(wnd);
    wnd.Show();
}
```

find window, for example

```
public MyCoolWindow FindWindowByKey(string windowKey)
{
    return windows.Where(w=>w.WindowKey == windowKey).SelectSingleOrDefault();
}
```

Just example.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use reflection to find all the `Windows` in your executing assembly:

```
var windows = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
             .GetTypes().OfType<Window>();
```

Once you have your collection of Windows, you can find any of them by name:

```
Window win = windows.SingleOrDefault( x => x.Name == "MyName" );
```